# What replaces the first class radio license?

Tags: united-states, legal

Several electricians here were hired partly because they had amateur radio licenses and one of them had a 'First Class Radiotelephone' license. It'd be nice to get that credential but it's no longer offered so what takes it's place?

[image]

Comment: I hope I'm deciphering the small image correctly, but this question is about the situation in the US; right? Added that tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The First Class and Second Class Radiotelephone Operator Licenses were replaced by the [General Radiotelephone Operator License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_radiotelephone_operator_license) (GROL) between 1981 and 1984. The GROL is nearer to the Second Class license than the First Class in the material that the exam covers.

Up until the 1970s, such a license was required to operate or perform maintenance on most kinds of broadcast radio stations or two-way base stations, but those requirements were progressively dropped, and today's GROL is [only required for certain marine and aircraft radios](https://www.fcc.gov/commercial-radio-operator-license-program). So there are fewer people with a reason to get it as compared to the old "first phone".